# Print file name and line number

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print the name of file along with line number, but it print the library name and its line number.

```py
#!/bin/env python3
# library source code (lib.py)
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo


def get_file_name():
        return __file__


def get_line():
        frameinfo = getframeinfo(currentframe())
        return f"[{frameinfo.filename}:{frameinfo.lineno}]"

def log(data):
        print(f"{get_line()} {data}")
```

```py
# program source code (program.py)
#!/bin/env python3


import lib


lib.log("hi")
```

Output:
**[/home/shubhapp/python3/codathon/doubt/lib.py:9] hi**

Expected output:
**[/home/shubhapp/python3/codathon/doubt/program.py:7] hi**

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_file_name():
        return __file__
```

`__file__` is returned from the namespace of the module itself, not from the caller. That's why you didn't get main.py, but test.py.

---

```
def get_line():
        frameinfo = getframeinfo(currentframe())
        return f"[{frameinfo.filename}:{frameinfo.lineno}]"
```

You are not getting desired output because currentframe() gave you the frame in which get_line was being *executed*, not where it was invoked. To get to the invocation point use the following approach:

```
get get_line():
    # fs means FrameSummary. 
    caller_fs = traceback.extract_stack()[0]
    filename, lineno = caller_fs.filename, caller_fs.lineno
    
    # Do whatever you want to do now.
```

If you want to see intermediate invocation points, you can use `traceback.print_stack()`.